# cph.plot(): how to make it bigger?

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to make my cph plot bigger, but unfortunately, it seems like figsize can't be applied on this plot! Can somebody help me please?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook on pandas!

cph.plot()

Here the problem is that the plot function actually plots my features, but they are too much so their names overlap and I can see nothing! I need the plot to be bigger!

Comment: Hi! Can you include a code example? My first intuition is that the `figsize` argument cannot be given to the `plot` function, but must be passed to the `figure` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [cph.plot()](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifelines.fitters.html#lifelines.fitters.kaplan_meier_fitter.KaplanMeierFitter.plot) calls [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) in the back-end. By default, Matplotlib uses the last created figure, so creating a figure with your specified width and height should do the trick:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# 8, 12 => width and height in inches
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 12))
cph.plot(/*your params here*/)
```

See if this works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(18,10)})
cph.plot()
```